# How do I replicate this website in terms of responsiveness using only css?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Here is the website I want to replicate: http://www.voncarcha.com/contact

Here is my website: http://foxweb.marist.edu/users/kf79g/contact.php

I mainly want to replicate his about page and contact page across all screen sizes that are large medium and small. How can I do this with only css like I did with all of my other pages besides the about page and contact page?

All of my code is located in the page source under these files (after right clicking view source on your browser):

screen_styles.css

screen_layout_large.css

screen_layout_small.css

screen_layout_medium.css

contact.php

about.php

I tried absolutely everything I could think of. I tried to replicate his website, but mine simply does not work as smoothly. Mine especially looks terrible on older browsers IE 7-9 and Firefox, while his does not for some reason. I want my site to be optimized to work across all browsers. I do not know what to do anymore. After this is done, my website will finally be finished. Please help me out I need to get this project done as soon as possible. I would really appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media Queries (currently what you're doing with responsive design) are the part of HTML5 and CSS3. So If you try these features in browsers that do not support HTML5, they will not work.

[This](https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/) link says, It can handle media queries in older browsers. You should take a look at it.

You can also take a look at [This one](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)

Comment: I tried inserting <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script> into both pages and it did not seem to work.

Comment: It only works sometimes, not completely. Is there any adjustments I should make to the actual code?